# A differential operator squared

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am not too sure how to find $$\alpha^2y(t)=0$$
$$
\alpha:= t\frac{d}{dt}
$$

I have tried the following
$$
t\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\frac{d}{dt}\right)\\
\frac{t}{dt}d\left(t\times\frac{d}{dt}\right)\\
\frac{t}{dt}\left(d(t)\times\frac{d}{dt}+t\times d\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)\right)\\
\frac{t}{dt}\left(\frac{d}{dt}+t \frac{d^2}{dt}\right)\\
t\frac{d}{dt^2}+t^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\\
\alpha^2 y(t)=0\implies  t\frac{dy}{dt^2}+t^2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=0
$$

I believe I've got a mistake in applying the product rule but I'm not too sure what went wrong. The extra $dy/dt^2$ term confuses me.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I added some lines check my edit

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you should have passed the whole $\frac{d}{dt}$ into the product, rather than just $d$ (?!). When you do that, you get the correct formulas:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}t\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\frac{d}{dt}\right)&=&
t\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\times\frac{d}{dt}\right)\\&=&
t\left(\frac{dt}{dt}\times\frac{d}{dt}+t\times \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)\right)\\&=&
t\left(\frac{d}{dt}+t \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\right)\\&=&
t\frac{d}{dt}+t^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\end{array}$$

so

$$\alpha^2 y(t)=0\implies  t\frac{dy}{dt}+t^2\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=0$$

Comment: I was skimming through _Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials_ and it showed me how to do _d(dy/dx)_. That's probably why I just moved the _d_ , oops!

Answer (score 0):

$$\alpha^2y(t)=\alpha (\alpha y(t))=\alpha (t\dfrac d{dt} y(t))=0$$
$$\alpha (ty')=t \dfrac {d}{dt}(ty')=t(ty')'=0$$
It finally gives :
$$t(y'+ty'')=0$$

---

**Edit:**
$$\frac{t}{dt}d\left(t\times\frac{d}{dt}\right )$$
This notation is not correct. Write it as:
$$t\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\times\frac{d}{dt}\right)=t\left(\frac{d}{dt}+t\times \dfrac {d^2}{dt^2}\right)$$